# launch subshell with different cwd and pass env variables

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, shell, subshell

I want to launch a subshell with its CWD to be of the child process, not the parent and at the same time pass in env variables.

```
REGION=$1
DEFAULT_MARKET=$2
NODE_ENV=$3
(cd ../core-services && exec PORT=3008 REGION=$REGION DEFAULT_MARKET=$DEFAULT_MARKET NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV node app/server/server.js)
```

this is what I have at the moment. When I run this script I get this following error.

```
Starting services with REGION=AA DEFAULT_MARKET=US NODE_ENV=local-qat2
./locale-changer.sh: line 37: exec: PORT=3008: not found
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

`exec` treats its first argument as the program to run, and doesn't allow variable assignments to precede the program. But there are a couple of other options: either prefix the `exec` command itself with the assignments you want (essentially, just move `exec` after the assignments):

```
(cd ../core-services && PORT=3008 REGION=$REGION DEFAULT_MARKET=$DEFAULT_MARKET NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV exec node app/server/server.js)
```

Or `export` the variables before running `exec` (variables can be exported from either the parent shell or the subshell):

```
export REGION=$1
export DEFAULT_MARKET=$2
export NODE_ENV=$3
(export PORT=3008; cd ../core-services && exec node app/server/server.js)
```